How to show language switcher to someone who is using an unknown language currently
In the settings page of my webapp, there is a language switcher.
But I wish to improve the switcher for the following users:

Users who wrongly selected a different language when a popup appeared to select their preferred language, some time ago.
Some users who missed changing language during onboarding
Some users who registered before I launched multi-lingual support to the entire app would be seeing English. And lets say the user do not know English - but they somehow managed to pass the onboarding as it was just phone number and OTP fields that were mandatory.

The solution I came up with looks like this  currently. The main point is to show all the available languages in brackets. as you can see - currently I support English, Thai and Chinese only.

But this doesn't scale when there are more languages in the future. 
Would like to learn from anyone who have solved this before. Or from somewhere you have seen this solved perfectly.

I see that google does it like this currently. But im not sure if it solves for all users though,


Does your system have a user profile page where users go to set their preferences?

Yes its available

This is just an idea, but maybe you could use the Google Translate icon instead of the globe logo. The logo is fairly well known and the user will be able to understand that this could translate the language of the application.


You can set a split button where the language button is with a language changing function.
This button doesn't have any text, but when clicked the user will see what its function is.


Appreciate that!! Let me try to build on this too, will keep you posted. The problem yet not solved is, lets say the 3 buttons here are an alien language copy, and you and I are looking for the language switcher button, we wouldn't know that the first button is the one. (I understand the use of the globe icon – but my small group of users I tested with, didn't get that.)

Seems there are three separate points to address in this question, they do relate, but should not be mixed blindly.

Can the users navigate to language selection?
Do the users know there are now (more) language options?
Can users select right language?

Well for

navigate to language selection: The symbolic navigation already looks solid enough that a user with goal to change language would not get lost. Note here that here a country flag (or flag symbol) can help as graphical hint - i.e. symbolic to "locale" and not defined to language
know are language options: I would detect where device locale is different from app setting and as a one-off offer to switch language. Displaying this offer in both languages. This does scale with each additional language
select right language: Have each language in the list display just in it's tongue. User will recognise their language. This is well solved.


What I can think of, is to show a visual clue along with the language text. so that means

with English you show US flag



with Chinese you show China flag


so if the user isn't able to read the text, which user cannot read, he/she would still be able to understand the visual clue i.e. the flag and that would help him make the correct selection.

I see, thanks for the reply. But I follow the "https://www.flagsarenotlanguages.com/blog/" concept. And I will have to pass on this potential solution suggestion.

Personally, I think all three problems are fictional, and real users won't face them.
Given that the user has chosen the wrong language and is basically unable to change it by themselves, I would go with a magical approach .
Simply suggest the right language
There are GeoIP databases (downloadable or SaaS) that can tell you from which location the user is accessing your product. Have a look https://www.maxmind.com/en/locate-my-ip-address
So if the location is Thailand and the current language is not Thai, show a popup in the local language (Thai), asking whether the user would like to switch to Thai: [Yes] [No] [Don't ask again].
There are many options for how exactly you ask—whether as a popup or a static message, and whether one time or recurring—depending on how strongly you want the user to switch language.

I like the idea, but it is only useful if someone mistakenly chose the wrong language, because I would always assume the default (and hopefully wanted) language based on the provided language of the browser or OS. The idea of a location check could be a nice to have backup method maybe. Although, GPS and IP checks require user approval for privacy reasons and can be dismissed. Also the site you posted shows my location as 18km away from where I am currently, so could provide the wrong language and leave a bad impression.

Absolutely, OP and developers have to consider how not to disturb regular users, say who use product on daily basis and therefore do fine and need no language tips.  There's always a room for a good thought  BTW 18km for IP check is very precise result!

It is not necessary to ask for the preferred language particularly; it could start by automatically detecting the country with the browser. Depending on the location, the most widely spoken language can be set. This is what most webapps currently do. Since you are registering phone numbers, country registration is already in place.
Language options work best if the icon is always visible on the top instead of hiding inside a menu. Either the language or the country or both should always be visible on the top. Given that language settings affect every other content, it is best to have that as a global setting at the top.

Note: This is Google translation, not sure if the translation is correct.

I like this pattern that Wordpress uses on their login page.

Why it's a good pattern:

The user encounters it as early in the workflow as possible (login)
The icon has both a Roman and a Mandarin character
Changing the value instantly changes everything on the page, so the user sees that it's a language selector

If your system doesn't require a frequent login (like an app that saves login tokens for six months), I'd put something like this on the user's profile page as close to their name as possible. Everyone clicks on their name or face to find their personal preferences... this avoids making them wade through system-level settings, which might be harder to navigate in another language.
